# How to use javascript variables in page redirect

Tags: javascript, http-redirect

I need to a redirect to a calendar url that includes month and year variables.  Is this viable in javascript?

```
    <script>
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const m = currentDate.getMonth();
        const y = currentDate.getFullYear();
        const myUrl = `www.somewhere.com/events.htm?pageComponentId=1234&month=${m}&year=${y}`;
        document.getElementById("currentDate").innerHTML = myUrl;
        document.location.assign(myUrl);
    </script>
```

Everything works except the document.location.assign(myUrl)  I have tried various ways to reference the variable myUrl but I clearly haven't wrapped my head around how to properly do this.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The URL is missing `https://` at the beginning. So `www.somewhere.com` is being interpreted as a subdirectory relative to the current URL.

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console? You would have seen the 404 error with the full URL.

Comment: You might also want to verify that your API is expecting 0-indexed months, because that's what is returned by [`Date.prototype.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). Else you can use `const m = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;`

Comment: Thanks, Barmar.  I was so focused on the variable I didn't notice the missing protocol.  With that fixed I'm getting a 403 and can't figure why.

Comment: Thanks, jsejcksn.  I was aware of the 0-9 wrinkle but appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All valid URLs follow a specific pattern: protocol, domain name, and path. In your URL the protocol is missing.

As `Barmar` mentioned, It will be interpreted as a subdirectory/path relative to the current URL.

```
// Add http or https
const myUrl = `https://www.somewhere.com/events.htm?pageComponentId=1234&month=${m}&year=${y}`;
```

**Example**

If the current URL is `https://example.com/something`, Then `document.location.assign("www.bingo.com");` will take you to `https://example.com/www.bingo.com`.

Comment: Thanks, BadPiggie.  I appreciate the further insight.